# Magento not sending any email's (eg,order,invoice,send email )

Tags: email, order-email

I am using magento 1.9.0.1 and using SMTP Pro Magento SMTP Email free extension i have configured it in right way before days ago my email was working good.but now after creating new oreder , invoice and after opening a order detail page and click on send email tab its giving message `The message has been sent.` and also after order opening its showing message `the invoice email was sent` can any body will tell me why this happening.

I have tried the bellow thing at my end.

1)I have checked all back end settings.

2)disabled extensions.

Comment: click on "run self test" , you will get the error

Comment: did you use aschorder's module?

Comment: its shows Test email was sent successfully.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Comment: @mujas yes i have used SMTP Pro Email Extension

Comment: what i need to set cron for this because currently i dont have any cron set.

Comment: check on the log files,if you are using aschorder's extension there will be a log file aschroder_smtppro.log(var/log)

Comment: refer this link http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/#more-2939

Comment: Check with Wolverine if Magneto keeps giving problems. If that doesn't work, enabling the cron should fix it. You can also test the cron manually by opening yourwebsite.com/cron.php in the browser.

Comment: @MilanSimek it showing blank

Comment: @mujas the a log file with aschroder_smtppro.log

Comment: @SanjayNakate, that's the intended behaviour. Try refreshing it a couple of times using ctrl+f5. It should then trigger the e-mail queue to be processed.

Comment: Here are some details on how to set up the cronjob: http://docs.klaviyo.com/article/172-set-up-magento-cron-job

Comment: @MilanSimek i am using aws instance

Comment: If you can connect using ssh you can do `crontab -e` to add a cronjob. Or check with aws on how to do that.

Comment: ok i will try this.

Comment: @MilanSimek as you say i had hit the mysite.com/cron.php 23 to 30 time but no mail found in inbox.

Comment: Ok, did you receive the test e-mail when using the Aschroder extension?

Comment: @MilanSimek yes i got the test mail.

Comment: i ab able to get test mail but not able to get order and any other email